# calling php class function in another function of same class using call_user_func_array

Tags: php

I have php class which looks something like the following.

```
class Foo{
function New_Function($functionName,$ParamsArray){
    $retValue = call_user_func_array($functionName,$ParamsArray);
    return $retValue;
}

function req_function(param1,param2){
    //Doing something
    }

function otherfunction($param1,$param2){
   $getval = $this->New_Function('req_function',array($param1,$param2));
   }
}
```

I want to call `req_function` from `otherfunction` which are functions of  same classes using `call_user_func_array` (because there are many functions like `req_functions`, hence i decided to use `call_user_func_array`) , but i am unable to do so, as i haven't used a `$this->` pointer which points to the parent class.

How do i make my program work?

Comment: `call_user_func_array([$this, "req_function"], $arguments)` ?!

Comment: The [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php) shows how to use an instance or a class method as a callback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code contains several errors. Please check the comments for details.

```
class Foo{
    function New_Function($functionName,$ParamsArray){
        // Call a class method by array(CLASS, METHOD)
        $retValue = call_user_func_array(array($this, $functionName),$ParamsArray);
        return $retValue;
    }

    // Leading dollar signs were missing
    function req_function($param1,$param2){
        echo "$param1: $param2";
    }

    function otherfunction($param1,$param2){
        $functionName = 'req_function'; // $functioName was not defined
        // Call $this->New_Function instead of New_Function
        $getval = $this->New_Function($functionName,array($param1,$param2)); 
    }
}

$test = new Foo();
$test->otherfunction("a", "b");
```

Comment: Tested here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d19a45ad2b86753b1209d81282c44751ae83cd00

Comment: `array($this, $functionName)` was enough to point out the answer. finding rest of mistakes was redundant and rude. Thanks Anyways. I will check and upvote.